# 1 Form, 2 Divs, JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that contains 2 divs, and in each div is an input, and when I press the buttons associated with each input, nothing happens and I believe it has something to do with the divs in the form. I know this code works when there wasn't the 2 divs, but I need to the divs so I can have the layout the way it is. Any suggestions?

I know I'd forgotten to add JQuery to this post, it was my mistake, but even with JQuery added it wasn't working in my project, in which this code is based.

Live code: https://jsfiddle.net/1brk3npL/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addLikes').click(function() {
    if ($('#likes').val() === "") {
      alert("Likes input is empty.");
    } else {
      $('#likesOutput').append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", $('#likes').val()).text($('#likes').val()));
    }
  });
  $('#removeLikes').click(function() {
    $('#likesOutput option:selected').remove();
  });

  $('#addDislikes').click(function() {
    if ($('#dislikes').val() === "") {
      alert("Dislikes input is empty.");
    } else {
      $('#dislikesOutput').append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", $('#dislikes').val()).text($('#dislikes').val()));
    }
  });
  $('#removeDislikes').click(function() {
    $('#dislikesOutput option:selected').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 250px;
}
input[type=text] {
  font-family: "ProximaRegular", sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preferenceDiv">
  <form id="preferenceInput">
    <div style="float:left; position:relative; width : 50%;">

      Likes:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="likes" />
      <br />
      <button id="addLikes" type="button">Add Likes</button>
      <button id="removeLikes" type="button">Remove Likes</button>
      <br />Selected Likes:
      <br />
      <select id="likesOutput" multiple="multiple"></select>

    </div>

    <div style="float:left; position:relative; width : 50%;">

      Dislikes:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="dislikes" />
      <br />
      <button id="addDislikes" type="button">Add Dislikes</button>
      <button id="removeDislikes" type="button">Remove Dislikes</button>
      <br />Selected Dislikes:
      <br />
      <select id="dislikesOutput" multiple="multiple"></select>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when you include jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/1brk3npL/1/

Comment: Your JSFiddle was wrong in two places: Include jQuery and run in head, not onload. See the snippet I made for you

Comment: This is weird; I forgot to include JQuery in my example, my mistake. But this example is meant to be representative of a project I'm working on and in that I've included JQuery and everything is done in a very similar fashion but that doesn't work. :( very weird

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there a way I can reference something in a specific div, so : 

$('# div1 addLikes').click(function(){DO SOMETHING});

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the code started working as intended yesturday. I don't know what happened, I didn't change the code in anyway. But one minute it wasn't working, then suddenly it was.

Answer (score -1):

Add jQuery and also add $ reference to jQuery.

Chnage the first line of the JS like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Even if you include jQuery there is reference missing. PLease change it and it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

Just Add below jquery library in this  https://jsfiddle.net/1brk3npL/ HTML part and see it's working :)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is not defined.

I just added jQuery on your jsfiddle and your code works.

**Click on Javascript options -> FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS -> Select jQuery version - > Click On Run**